# previous state persisting even after calling setState() with new data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a task app using Firebase Cloud Firestore

I have added a `realtime listener` for re-rendering the Flatlist with new tasks if any are added.

But I am facing an issue such that the `state tasks = []` is getting appended to the `old state` which results in duplication of Tasks in Flatlist.

I wish to just refresh the whole list.

This is my code for the realtime listener:

```js
this.state = {
      tasks: [],
    };

fetchTasks() {
    try {
      this.setState({loading: true});
      const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
      const tempTasks = [];
      firestore()
        .collection('Tasks')
        .where('uid', '==', `${uid}`)
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log('realtime: ', JSON.stringify(doc.data(), null, 2));
            tempTasks.push({
              taskId: doc.id,
              data: doc.data(),
            });
          });
          this.setState({tasks: []});
          this.setState({tasks: tempTasks, loading: false});
          console.log('tasks: ', this.state.tasks.length);
        });
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({loading: false});
      Alert.alert('Error fetching tasks', `${e}`, [{text: 'OK'}]);
      console.log('err in realtime', e);
    }
  }

render() {
   return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.tasks}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    )
```

Initially: One task
[image]

Final: After adding a task, duplicate of Task 1 also appear as the `tasks = []` is appended in the state instead of refreshing with both task 1 and task 2.

[image]

Log of tempTasks:

```
tempTasks [
  {
    "taskId": "FljhGGlsFN7yrD4GajDe",
    "data": {
      "status": "pending",
      "createdOn": {
        "_seconds": 1578761968,
        "_nanoseconds": 66000000
      },
      "title": "Task 1",
      "deadline": {
        "_seconds": 1578761940,
        "_nanoseconds": 0
      },
      "description": "apsdfplsdv",
      "author": "yashGmail",
      "uid": "t2kHrhIMbLggj2BpxKbJrPW9GL42"
    }
  },
  {
    "taskId": "GhF5nYalbTZZZH5j2lNO",
    "data": {
      "status": "pending",
      "createdOn": {
        "_seconds": 1578762188,
        "_nanoseconds": 226000000
      },
      "title": "Task 2",
      "deadline": {
        "_seconds": 1578761940,
        "_nanoseconds": 0
      },
      "description": "asdvlksdk",
      "author": "yashGmail",
      "uid": "t2kHrhIMbLggj2BpxKbJrPW9GL42"
    }
  }
]
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if event `.onSnapshot(snapshot => {})` is triggered with only the newer elements or it gets triggered with all the elements. From your code it is clear that you are updating `state.tasks` with `tempTasks` so it is very much clear that data inside `tempTasks` is also duplicate, the reason for which I have explained above.

You can try this if `onSnapshot` is triggered with all the data:

```
firestore()
.collection('Tasks')
.where('uid', '==', `${uid}`)
.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot) // This to check what data is inside snapshot
  const tempTasks = snapshot.map(doc => ({
    taskId: doc.id,
    data: doc.data(),
  }))
  this.setState({tasks: tempTasks, loading: false});
})
```

Comment: This works for adding new tasks, but when a task is deleted and the listener is called the wrong task is deleted from the ```state.tasks = []```, for example, if I delete Task 1, Task 3 disappears from the ```state.tasks = []```. Although the listeners query  results are correct and Task 1 is only deleted.

Comment: Check your `snapshot` parameter. As you can see the logic here is bare simple, to just add the data you are getting in the snapshot to the state. So if the data is wrong it means you are deleting the wrong data or something else is getting wrong.